# How to add Number keyboard in otp page and number field in address area of android apk in visual studio code with cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

I have used to create otp page and keyboard layout in below format. Please tell me the solution to get number keyboard in this code.

```
<div class="fieldWrapInner">
  <span><input type="password" id="codeBox1" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="1" 
         onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(1, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(1)" ng-model="Val1"/></span>
  <span><input type="password" id="codeBox2" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="1" 
         onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(2, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(2)" ng-model="Val2"/></span>
  <span><input type="password" id="codeBox3" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="1" 
         onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(3, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(3)" ng-model="Val3"/></span>
  <span><input type="password" id="codeBox4" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="1" 
         onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(4, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(4)" ng-model="Val4"/></span>
</div>
```

And also please help to add number keyboard to mobile number field in address field. This is the code I used

```
<span class="fieldWrap">      
 <input type="text" name="MobileNo1" ng-model="Address.MobileNo1" maxlength="50" placeholder="{{'Telephone/Mobile:'|translate}}" ng-required="true">
</span>
```

Comment: Where is code? !!!